# Python liskov substition principle and custom init

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, liskov-substitution-principle

I am writing classes with custom init functions that provide async initialization. This all works well, except that when I create a subclass and override the async init function, mypy tells me I am violating the liskov substitution principle.  This leaves me with two questions:

- How can I change my code so mypy understands that the function signature is different on purpose? Similarly to `__init__`. My goal is to make ImplA and ImplB as simple as possible as these are classes implemented by my users. AsyncInit can be super complicated.
- Does `__init__` violate the liskov substitution principle?

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Any

TChild = TypeVar("TChild", bound="AsyncInit")


class AsyncInit:
    @classmethod
    async def new(cls: Type[TChild], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> TChild:
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        await self.ainit(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore # ignore that TChild does not have `ainit` for now
        return self


class ImplA(AsyncInit):
    async def ainit(self, arg1: int, arg2: float) -> None:
        self.a = arg1
        self.b = arg2


class ImplB(ImplA):
    async def ainit(self, arg1: str, arg2: float, arg3: int) -> None:
        await super().ainit(arg2, arg3)
        self.c = arg1
```

Comment: I'm currently not experienced with [tag:mypy] (but surely I will check it out soon). LSP, as I understand it, is about *using* objects, not about object *creation* (or initialization). Did you try the same with `__init__`?

Comment: If you do the same with `__init__` everything works fine. There appears to be some kind of exception.

Comment: I have difficulty accepting that your actual goal is to make the initialization of objects asynchronous. In my opinion, it should be possible to break it apart into (1) true initialization (setting start values to member variables) and (2) some preparation code that may take much longer to execute. I'd think about making the second part asynchronous. It's of course also possible to parallelize object creation by delegating it to some factory (method).

Comment: As for `__init__`, this is exactly what I would expect: Object creation is not considered part of the public interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization *from a class* is generally not covered by LSP, which is concerned with the substitution of *instances*. As per [the definition of LSP](https://doi.org/10.1145%2F197320.197383): (emphasis mine)

> Subtype Requirement: Let ϕ(x) be a property provable about **objects x of type T**. Then ϕ(y) should be true for **objects y of type S** where S is a subtype of T.

In Python's lingo, "objects x of type T" are "instances of T". As such, operations on type T itself are *not* covered by LSP. In specific, that means instantiation between subtypes does not need to be substitutable.

As such, both `__new__` and `__init__` are commonly exempt by type checkers from subtyping constraints as their *canonical usage* is during instantiation.

---

Things are trickier for alternate constructors via `classmethod`: a `classmethod` can be – and *commonly is* – called on an instance. As such, a `classmethod` is considered part of the instance behaviour and thus subject to subtyping constraints by type checkers.
This especially applies to alternate *initializers* which are not distinguishable from regular methods.

There is currently no proper way to make the initializers well-typed (e.g. by parameterizing over parameters) nor alternative designs with equal usability (e.g. external constructors registered for the type).
The simplest means is to actually tell the type checker that a method is not part of subtyping constraints. For MyPy, this is done via `# type: ignore [override]`.

```py
class ImplB(ImplA):
    async def ainit(self, arg1: str, arg2: float, arg3: int) -> None:  # type: ignore [override]
        await super().ainit(arg3, arg2)
        self.c = arg1
```

---

However, it is usually worth to consider whether an alternate `async` construction *that is not comparable across subtypes* actually makes sense: it means the caller already has `async` capability (to `await` the construction) *and* has to use custom code per class (to provide specific arguments) anyway.
This means it is usually possible to pull the *entire* `async` construction out into the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct - your classes as implemented require the caller to know exactly the type of the object they're operating on (`ImplA` versus `ImplB`) in order to be able to call `ainit`, but by having one derived from the other you're implying (or, indeed, stating) that they shouldn't need to know.

Perhaps what you actually need is a class in between `ImplA`/`ImplB` and `AsyncInit` that knows how to do the common work from `ainit` in a separate method that the two derived classes can then call from their `ainit` methods. Both `ImplA` and `ImplB` would then derive from this new class instead of each other. That way `ainit` is not an "overridden" method and can have a different signature.

For example:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Any

TChild = TypeVar("TChild", bound="AsyncInit")


class AsyncInit:
    @classmethod
    async def new(cls: Type[TChild], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> TChild:
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        await self.ainit(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore # ignore that TChild does not have `ainit` for now
        return self


class NewBaseClass(AsyncInit):
    async def _ainit(self, arg1: int, arg2: float) -> None:
        self.a = arg1
        self.b = arg2


class ImplA(NewBaseClass):
    async def ainit(self, arg1: int, arg2: float) -> None:
        await super()._ainit(arg1, arg2)


class ImplB(NewBaseClass):
    async def ainit(self, arg1: str, arg2: float, arg3: int) -> None:
        await super()._ainit(arg3, arg2)
        self.c = arg1
```

I should note that I've flipped the order of the arguments in `await super().ainit(arg2, arg3)` from your original code such that the types match what the called method expects.

Comment: I fear this does not give me the behaviour I want. My users could create any class with any init parameters that inherit from ImplA, for example. I cannot create a common base class that supports that in the way you propose. I am looking to support behaviour similar to python's `__init__ `but with added async functionality.

Comment: You could have them pass a dictionary in to the method and fill that dictionary with the relevant parameters. I'm not sure there's a huge number of options that don't break some assumption or another.